# How can I overclock my monitor to 80hz?

Tags: nvidia, xorg, display, display-resolution, overclocking

Still learning linux. Yes, my monitor supports 80hz, tested and confirmed on Windows.

So here's what I've tried to far.

1. `cvt 1920 1080 80` + `--newmode` + `--addmode` in `xrandr` which resulted in

```
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  41
  Current serial number in output stream:  42
```

2. The good ol' [EDID trick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0NdNq0OmkY&t) which doesn't work anymore. Results in a blank kernel cmd line. The moment I revert changes to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` in root shell recovery mode everything boots normally.
3. Editing ViewPortIn in NVIDIA X Server Settings which results in my additions to it being deleted. I tried entering `1920x1080_80.00` and `1920x1080_80` which both get deleted before I can hit apply.

Any other ideas? Thanks.

`xrandr` outputs:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   640x480       75.00    59.94  
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Answer (score 0):

create modelines:

`cvt 1920 1080 80`

after use `xrandr --newmode --addmode --outputmode`

Comment: Yes, that's the first thing I tried which didn't work. I left out the `cvt` part, my bad.